# What are challenges in writing SQL parser in ANTLR?

Tags: mysql, sql, parsing, antlr, yacc

I'm trying to define schedule and estimate the effort required for implementing ANTLR parser of MySQL dialect of SQL. Basically, it boils down to translating YACC parser grammar from MySQL release (`sql_yacc.yy`) to ANTRL grammar.

Does it only seem so straighforward? I found that some areas of the language syntax may require some more development and testing:

- ANTLR does not accept left-recursion
- numeric literals will require custom Java code to cast types based on values
- ...

Any other challenges you know, encountered or expect?

Comment: A parser alone only gives you an AST. If you want to do anything of use with the result of the parser, don't just skim over that. And if not, why bother?

Comment: @delnan, right, this is the next step of the project. The output of parsing will be evaluated by another component and I need to define in what form it should be (rewritten tree, some domain model,...)

Comment: @dzieciou:  To do anything else, you'll need an AST (a parser does not give you an AST, you still have to work to produce one).  You will likely then need symbol tables, and to do anything else, you'll need tools to navigate/analyze/manipulate.  See my notes on Life After Parsing: http://www.semdesigns.com/products/DMS/LifeAfterParsing.html

Answer (score 3):

Before do this, you should know this is a job can't be finished in several days or weeks, but in several months. Here is a sql parser library you may reference when you create your own parser.

http://www.sqlparser.com/

Comment: Several months just to parse SQL and report "syntax error" or "correct" and maybe build a tree? Surely not for someone who has experience with parsing (e.g. a good fraction of CS bachelors).

Comment: @Kaz: SQL is a very large language.